How do I fix consistently reverting to hacked index.php and .htaccess files?
The index.php and .htaccess files on my site patrickkingart.com keep reverting to hacked versions that are making the front end of my site inaccessible. I can still access the WordPress dashboard.
I also sometimes find random php files in my root directory, and other times find the entire file structure has been deleted.
I've tried deleting, renaming, reuploading, repairing with Wordfence, restoring from backups, reinstalling WordPress, but index.php and .htaccess still revert back to hacked versions with the file permission 444.
Edit: this is what .htaccess reverts to. I'm not 100% sure but I think this might be what's causing the index.php to revert:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


Please read [tour], server security questions probably belong at either ServerFault or a security Stack site.  Opinion: if you don't have the free time to keep a WP site secure you might want to move it to hosting with WPEngine or Wordpress.

I've had my site on GoDaddy for since 2017 and just now in the last couple of weeks have I been having issues with this.

Your wordpress site has been hacked. But the htaccess code you posted is perfectly normal, so you should look somewhere else. There are a lot of ways to hack a wordpress site, so you should google it and follow all the steps in tutorials to unhack your site.

Your site has been hacked, so whatever strategy you have to supply needed security updates has failed and needs to be changed.  Again, just my opinion.

If you're on GoDaddy's shared hosting, if any of the other sites on that shared hosting server are compromised it's possible to move across from server to server. There may also be some code hidden in a plugin directory or the theme directory that allows the hacker to repeatedly add in malicious code.  You're going to need to do a full cleaning and also migrate your site to a better hosting platform.

This is a general issue with simple CMS systems like wordpress - they cannot be secure, they are vulnerable by idiotic design. They insist in being able to modify their own code, which is a no go for a web application. Chose a different base for your site that does not have that requirement and upload the code such that it is not writable by the http server process. You obviously need a hosting company that actually allows that. Best bet is not to rely on a cheap web hoster, but operate your own (virtual) service, although that means you are responsible for things like backup youself.
